# How to handle java8 installation issue when building h2o docker image [using Dockerfile in the repository]

Tags: oracle, docker, java-8, h2o

I'm trying to build an H2o docker image, using https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/Dockerfile.

It gets the following error:

*E: Package 'oracle-java8-installer' has no installation candidate*

The command '/bin/sh -c echo 'DPkg::Post-Invoke {"/bin/rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb || true";};' | tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/no-cache &&   echo "deb http://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/ubuntu xenial main universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list &&   apt-get update -q -y &&   apt-get dist-upgrade -y &&   apt-get clean &&   rm -rf /var/cache/apt/* &&   DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y wget unzip python-pip python-sklearn python-pandas python-numpy python-matplotlib software-properties-common python-software-properties &&   add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java &&   apt-get update -q &&   echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | debconf-set-selections &&   echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 seen true | debconf-set-selections &&   DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer &&   apt-get clean &&   wget http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/latest_stable -O latest &&   wget --no-check-certificate -i latest -O /opt/h2o.zip &&   unzip -d /opt /opt/h2o.zip &&   rm /opt/h2o.zip &&   cd /opt &&   cd `find . -name 'h2o.jar' | sed 's/.\///;s/\/h2o.jar//g'` &&   cp h2o.jar /opt &&   /usr/bin/pip install `find . -name "*.whl"` &&   cd / &&   wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/h2oai/h2o-3/master/docker/start-h2o-docker.sh &&   chmod +x start-h2o-docker.sh &&   wget http://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-training/mnist/train.csv.gz &&   gunzip train.csv.gz &&   wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laurendiperna/Churn_Scripts/master/Extraction_Script.py  &&   wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laurendiperna/Churn_Scripts/master/Transformation_Script.py &&   wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laurendiperna/Churn_Scripts/master/Modeling_Script.py' returned a non-zero code: 100

I'm assuming it may be related to the recent Oracle JDK License Update.

Is there a way to resolve this error in building the docker image?

Comment: are you following the walkthrough here: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/welcome.html?#docker-users, if not can you list the your steps and a bit about your OS? thanks!

Comment: Hi Lauren, I had used the same Dockerfile as in the Dockerfile template. The error was related to installation of java 8.

Comment: hi parvin, are you still having issues? are you running this on linux or some other os?

Comment: Hi Lauren, i'm using Mac os. I already had docker set up.  and used https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/Dockerfile for building the image. It got failed in step related to java-8-installation

Comment: parvin, please also feel free to create a jira ticket (http://jira.h2o.ai) for the needed update. thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Thanks Lauren, I will create the ticket also.

Comment: @Lauren, Here is the link to the JIRA ticker id : PUBDEV-6453

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it the pkg appears to have been removed from the repository. I created the following on Mar 26th and it built successfully that day...

```
From ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y  software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y
RUN apt-get update
RUN echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections
RUN apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer
```

And today this is the result

```
Step 8/8 : RUN apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer
 ---> Running in 1bba5bac63e9
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Package oracle-java8-installer is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'oracle-java8-installer' has no installation candidate
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

I've already moved to OpenJDK and am experimenting with Corretto

**Update**:

The PPA has been discontinued... see their notice here:
https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java

Comment: Sure... accept and or upvote the answer and I'll get that much closer to the clouds... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use openjdk-8 instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I found the following image which is a prebuilt image to run h2o flow UI .

https://hub.docker.com/r/h2oai/h2o-open-source-k8s